# Usage of "in this list" - "on this list"

Tags: lists

Do you use "in this list" and "on this list" in the following way?

a) In this list, when talking indirectly about the contents of the list.

Example:

- Have you participated in this list? (Not this one)

This one: - I do not see any problem in this list.

b) On this list, when talking directly about the contents of the list.

Example:

- The individuals on this list are from this town.

Comment: I think you're mixing up two different contexts (I assume *Have you participated in this list?* is intended to mean *Were you **involved in the creation** of this list?*, but native speakers probably wouldn't phrase it that way).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. OK, thanks. I see that "in" goes with "participated" (to participate in) and not with "this list". Then, what about "problem in this list". The list is not about problems. If I say "I do not see any problem on this list", could it be I am looking for the word "problem" on the list?

Comment: It might depend on the exact sense intended. If you *don't see any problems **on** a list* (or ***in*** it; they'd be interchangeable there), that would normally imply you've looked at each item in the list, and decided none of them are problematic for you. But I think native speakers would more likely just say they  *don't see/have any problem **with** the list* (treating the list collectively, but note that *problem* there would normally be in the singular).